# I want Sweet alert to work first to change the check to true, false, what to do?

Tags: javascript, c#, html, jquery

**I want Sweet alert to work first to change the check to true, false, what to do? Please help me !**

```
$("#our-table").on('click', '#button-delete', function () {
    var check = null;

    Swal.fire({
        title: 'Are you sure ?',
        icon: 'warning',
        showCancelButton: true,
        confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
        cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
        confirmButtonText: 'Comfirm'
    }).then((result) => {
        if (result.isConfirmed) {
            check == true
        } 
    })

    if (check == true) {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: What's your goal? You will make your check to true or false then show something(or return something) when sweetalert's confirm is clicked?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly if you want to return true or false according to sweetalert's confirmation, you can pass a callback function and return the checked value in this way:

```js
function sweetChecked(callback) {
    Swal.fire({
        title: 'Are you sure ?',
        icon: 'warning',
        showCancelButton: true,
        confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
        cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
        confirmButtonText: 'Comfirm'
    }).then((result) => {
        callback(result.isConfirmed);
    })
}

$("#button-delete").on('click', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var URLToRedirect = event.currentTarget.getAttribute('href');
    console.log(URLToRedirect);
    sweetChecked(function (checked) {
        if (checked) {
            console.log("true");
            window.location.href = URLToRedirect;
        }
        else {
            console.log("false");
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"
    integrity="sha256-9/aliU8dGd2tb6OSsuzixeV4y/faTqgFtohetphbbj0=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@10.12.5/dist/sweetalert2.all.min.js"></script>

<a id="button-delete" href="/ManageUser/Delete/01">Delete</a>
```

Comment: Sorry But the button I pressed I use <a href> tag which takes me to the link without waiting for sweet alert to work.

Comment: Can you explain your goal a little bit?

Comment: If you want to get the checked value first then go to a URL, that can be done as well.

Comment: I have a delete button which sends a get value to delete the data, and I want it to alert first, which I use tag <a id="button-delete" href ="/ManageUser/Delete/01"> 
But what happens is that there is no notification and the value will be sent as soon as I press it.

Comment: What would you do with href after deleting?

Comment: When pressing <a> I want Sweet alert to ask first, and if I click confirm, take to / ManageUser / Delete / id.

Comment: @TeeAdkins, check my updated answer. First you need to stop the default event of the anchor tag, then you can go to the next page by getting `href` from the anchor tag.

Comment: Well done !. Thank you very much brother. You are my idol

Comment: I think, your question is not a duplicate of another which is marked as duplicated.

Answer (score 0):

Think the only thing you need to change is

```
 if (result.isConfirmed) {
     check = true
   }
```

The == is actually doing a check instead of an assignment.